# Problem in get data on using retrofit2 on newer Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2.6

I am using retrofit2 in kotlin to connect to the api
I get data from API without any problems in Android API 22
But when I test the same program on Android API 30, it gives me the following answer and does not return any value in the API answer.

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://Examples.com/api/login?email=xxxxx%40yahoo.com&password=123
    Content-Length: 0
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (0-byte body)
```

I do the following

```
fun client() : OkHttpClient{
    return OkHttpClient.Builder().
        addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }).
    connectTimeout(mConnection_TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            writeTimeout(mConnection_TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            readTimeout(mConnection_TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
}

fun getRetrofit() : Retrofit
{
    return Retrofit.Builder().
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL).
            client(client())
        .build()
}
```

This problem occurs on both Emulator and mobile phones

Comment: Do you have some logs that you can post in order to provide more info? Server response log would be helpful

Comment: This isn't a question with a useful repro or an error.

Comment: @georkost I sent the answer of the software in the text of the question after connecting to the server, The same api and the same program works properly on Android 5

Comment: @YuriSchimke I also know this is not an error, my question is why in Android 5 it receives data correctly but in Android 10 you say no data was found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have trouble retrieving information from retrofit2 on newer Android, just add the following value to the file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    . . .  .
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
```